# django custom tag to pass a certain field into a filter

Tags: django, tags

I am using django-simple-history to record changes to a model, I've written a bunch of custom methods for the model to extract the latest change date from the history, one for each field I'm interested in but it's a lot of duplication and really not at all DRY.

It seems to me that I should be able to simplify this using a custom tag and passing the field that I want but I can't seem to get it to work.

customtags.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_latest_record(issue, field):
    record = issue.history.filter(field = 1).most_recent
    return record
```

in my template:

```
{% get_latest_record issue 'name_of_field' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make shure your `customtags.py` file is in `templatetags` directory (`__init__.py` is also required) and then restart server

```
polls/
__init__.py
models.py
templatetags/
    __init__.py
    poll_extras.py
views.py
```

Then in template `{% load customtags %}`

Comment: Already had that in place.  I actually got something working but then it was returning an object and I could not access the object's attributes from the template anyway so I revered to having a very non-dry set of methods in the model.